# Multiline object in JavaScript. How to loop through it?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have an object in javascript

```
var o = [
  {city: 'armenia', population: 300000}, 
  {city: 'russia', population: 1200000}
];
```

I need to loop through it; please help

Comment: you mean iterate through it? for(var i=0;i<o.length;i++){//do whatever}...

Comment: That's an array you have there. You can loop through it like any other array...

Comment: this is not an object; it's an array of objects..

Comment: @Jonathan its an array of objects, you can't loop thru the objects like the array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529403/javascript-loop-through-object-array

Answer (score 0):

This question been answered before. Needless to say loop thru the array using the length property and loop thru the object using a `foreach` loop. [for each...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in)

```
for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
      var obj = o[i];

      for (var key in obj) {
           // key
           console.log(key);

           // value
           console.log(obj[key]);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
o.forEach(function (c) {
  console.log(c.city, c.population); // "armenia" 300000, "russia" 1200000
})
```

*or*

```
for(var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
  console.log(o[i].city, o[i].population);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/boluhivi/1/edit)**