# how to iterate the below array in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Please help me to iterate the below array in jquery and get each value .

```
var data = [{"value":"150000","completion":"10.00","coal":"32.40","local":"144.00","bacs":"35.00","landRegistry":"200.00","solFee":"395.00","vatOnSolFees":79,"stampDuty":1500,"total":2395.4},{"value":"120000","completion":"1.00","coal":"3.40","local":"14.00","bacs":"3.00","landRegistry":"100.00","solFee":"35.00","vatOnSolFees":7,"stampDuty":150,"total":395.4}];
```

Comment: use a loop man a loop :)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529403/javascript-loop-through-object-array, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626735/how-to-loop-through-an-array-containing-objects-and-access-their-properties. There are a *lot* of questions on this already if you search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a jquery each to loop through the elements of the array

```js
    var data = [{"value":"150000","completion":"10.00","coal":"32.40","local":"144.00","bacs":"35.00","landRegistry":"200.00","solFee":"395.00","vatOnSolFees":79,"stampDuty":1500,"total":2395.4},{"value":"120000","completion":"1.00","coal":"3.40","local":"14.00","bacs":"3.00","landRegistry":"100.00","solFee":"35.00","vatOnSolFees":7,"stampDuty":150,"total":395.4}];
    
    $.each(data,function(i,v){
       console.log(v.value);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

if you want to loop over the objects add another loop

```js
var data = [{
  "value": "150000",
  "completion": "10.00",
  "coal": "32.40",
  "local": "144.00",
  "bacs": "35.00",
  "landRegistry": "200.00",
  "solFee": "395.00",
  "vatOnSolFees": 79,
  "stampDuty": 1500,
  "total": 2395.4
}, {
  "value": "120000",
  "completion": "1.00",
  "coal": "3.40",
  "local": "14.00",
  "bacs": "3.00",
  "landRegistry": "100.00",
  "solFee": "35.00",
  "vatOnSolFees": 7,
  "stampDuty": 150,
  "total": 395.4
}];


$.each(data, function(i, v) {
  $.each(v, function(index, value) {
    console.log(index + ':' + value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried the above code but i am not able to go inside loop and no error is generated

Comment: see the console for errors

Comment: Hey i want one more help from u bro i want to add edit and delete button in below code of html table .... I am creating table based on JSON now i want to add two column in the same table Edit and Delete . PLease Help

Comment: Please find code Below :

Comment: My Json : function CreateTableFromJSON() {
        var myBooks = [
            {
                "Book ID": "1",
                "Book Name": "Computer Architecture",
                "Category": "Computers",
                "Price": "125.60"
            },
            {
                "Book ID": "2",
                "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book",
                "Category": "Programming",
                "Price": "56.00"
            },
            
        ]

Comment: var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
            for (var key in myBooks[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }

        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);   

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");     
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

Comment: @user6773905 create another question so we can help