# Javascript: a variable is returning two values, one of them undefined. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game involving asteroids. I have a collision detection function that looks something like this:

```
function collisions(){
  for (j=asteroids.length-1;j>=0;j++){
    //do stuff with asteroids[j]
  }
}
```

I tried doing the collision math with the asteroids, but I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

My main problem is that when I wrote:

```
console.log(asteroids[j])
```

It logged two values, the Asteroid object, and undefined. I thought maybe it was logging undefined from somewhere else, so I wrote:

```
console.log("1", asteroids[j], "2")
```

and it returned both the Asteroid object, and undefined, both with a "1" before and a "2" after. Does asteroids[j] have both values? What is happening here? How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript loop through object array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529403/javascript-loop-through-object-array) and possibly [How to loop through an array containing objects and access their properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626735/how-to-loop-through-an-array-containing-objects-and-access-their-properties)

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `j--` in the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decrement (`i--`) the loop instead increment (`i++`).

```
for (j=asteroids.length-1;j>=0;j--){
  //do stuff with asteroids[j]
}
```

Comment: Thank you haha, I usually do, it just completely whoosed me here.

Comment: It is ok ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You start the loop with `asteroids.length-1` which is the last element ant then increment `j++` the index. This pushes you outside the array in the second iteration itself. Hence you get the second as `undefined`. Javascript does not throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` like errors. It has `undefined` which says it all. Hence you get an `undefined` for trying to access something out of bound of the array.