# How to show JSON with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am currently researching the JSON and JS (JSON.parse()). Firstly, I need to write this text through JSON and then to show it with JavaScript in HTML in this format (as a list). I know how to show the first artist but don't know how to show the rest of them.

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Artists</h2>
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>

var json =[{
        "name": "Deep purple",
        "title1": "Machine Head",
        "title2": "Stormbringer"
    },
    {
        "name": "Joe Satriani",
        "title1": "Flying in a Blue Dream",
        "title2": "The Extremist",
        "title3": "Shockwave Supernova"
    },
    {
        "name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "title1": "The Doggfather",
        "title2": "Snoopified"
    }
];



var obj = JSON.parse(json);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<ul><li>'+ obj[0].name+ '</li>';   //what now???

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any advice would be helpful.
[image]

Comment: Start to loop.... It is an array

Comment: I know I need a loop but don't know how to write that. I'm new with js.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: So you build a string in the loop

Comment: What makes this hard is the fact titles should be an array, but for some reason it is not.

Comment: Please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529403/javascript-loop-through-object-array

Comment: So I guess I need a different json structure?

Comment: You should render this server side if it is just placed in the document as you have it here. your `json` is not really JSON it is a JavaScript Object not a string that can be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Without using `document.write`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

You can loop through `JSON` using [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and a more functional way is using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You can generate your content to append the desired DOM element (`div#demo` in your case).

```js
var json = [{
    "name": "Deep purple",
    "title1": "Machine Head",
    "title2": "Stormbringer"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe Satriani",
    "title1": "Flying in a Blue Dream",
    "title2": "The Extremist",
    "title3": "Shockwave Supernova"
  },
  {
    "name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "title1": "The Doggfather",
    "title2": "Snoopified"
  }
];


var content = json.map(function(obj){
  var con = "<h3>" + obj.name + "</h3>";
  con += "<ul>";
  con += Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
      return key.startsWith("title") ? "<li>" + obj[key] + "</li>" : "";
  }).join('');
  con += "</ul>";
  return con;
}).join('');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<h2>Artists</h2>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var json = [{
    "name": "Deep purple",
    "title1": "Machine Head",
    "title2": "Stormbringer"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe Satriani",
    "title1": "Flying in a Blue Dream",
    "title2": "The Extremist",
    "title3": "Shockwave Supernova"
  },
  {
    "name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "title1": "The Doggfather",
    "title2": "Snoopified"
  }
];
json.forEach((jsonObject) => {
  var name = jsonObject.name;
  var titles = [];
  Object.keys(jsonObject).filter((key) => {
    return key.startsWith("title")
  }).forEach((title) => {
    titles.push(jsonObject[title]);
  })
  var root = document.getElementById("demo");
  render(root, titles, name)
});

function render(root, array, name) {
  var nameElement = document.createElement('h3');
  nameElement.innerHTML = name;
  root.appendChild(nameElement)
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  var array;
  root.appendChild(ul); // append the created ul to the root
  array.forEach(function(item) {
    li = document.createElement('li'); // create a new list item
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item)); // append the text to the li
    ul.appendChild(li); // append the list item to the ul
  });
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h2>Artists</h2>
  <div id="demo"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: probably `key.startsWith("title")` to be not equal to "name" instead? Also might be better to create `ul` elements append child `li` elements then append the whole thing to the DOM at the end.

Comment: NOTE I DO like the `filter` on the `Object.keys` here and was thinking along those lines.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss updated based on comments and his question

Comment: Great! this will now also work if the JSON is from ajax and renders in a return from that.  Good change.